# How to hide/close Current Form and opens a new form using a button inside the UserControl ? C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

[This is how I made the main form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSvv0.png)

Basically, I want to open a new form (dashboard) using a button inside the usercontrol. The usercontrol is fill in the mainform's panel (login).

```
 private void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtUsername.Text == "admin" && txtPassword.Text == "admin")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Successfully");
            DASHBOARD dashboard = new DASHBOARD();
            dashboard.ShowDialog();

        }
    }
```

I did try this block of code but it won't close the mainform

```
MainForm mainform = new MainForm();
mainform.Hide();
DASHBOARD dashboard = new DASHBOARD();
dashboard.ShowDialog();
mainform.Close();
```

Comment: You mean `this.ParentForm.Hide();` -- Don't create a new instance of an object to refer to an existing instance. Changes to  the new instance don't affect the other.

Comment: @Jimi thanks, it's working now. I already tried that one earlier and it wasn't working lol. idk even know why.

Comment: @Jimi Hi, kindly post your comment as an answer so that I can mark it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code creates a new instance and closes it hidden. However, this doesn't affect the main window as they are not related.

```
MainForm mainform = new MainForm();
mainform.Hide();
mainform.Close();
```

`this.ParentForm.Hide();` can complete the operation of hiding the main window.

usercontrol：

[image]

code：

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsControlLibrary1
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.textBox1.Text == "admin" && this.textBox2.Text == "admin")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Successfully");
                UserForm dashboard = new UserForm();
                this.ParentForm.Hide();
                dashboard.ShowDialog();
                this.ParentForm.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mainform:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a WinForms app, I take it.  You can't close the Main Form without terminating the application. The only thing running above that is the Program static instance.  If I read this right, the effect you're looking for can be achieved with *Panels*.  A panel is just a control that contains other controls.  You can have a panel for login and another for dashboard and switch between them by the simple expedient of which one you decide is on top at any given moment.

Another possible approach is to make a tiny hidden Main Form whose sole function is to spawn other forms but it is never actually displayed at all.

I'm curious, though.  Why don't you put the dashboard in the main form, and when the main form has loaded, have it spawn a Modal Login Dialog?  Once login is complete, destroy the login dialog and the dashboard is now your main display by default, or if login fails, then you can keep respawning the login dialog until the login succeeds or you decide that the user is a Bad Actor and you abort the application entirely.  It seems the login is the transient function, so code it as such.

Comment: The OP is closing the starting form only after `dashboard.ShowDialog();` returns, which is probably meant to close the app when the Dashboard closes.

Comment: If the dashboard dialog is done, then all that is required is to call `this.Close();` on the main form.